# Lotus API getAllReadEntries throughs not implemented error in Eclipse

Tags: lotus-notes

I am trying to get Read/Unread documents from Lotus notes, I can connect using this code:

```
package mypackage.Notes.GetRead;
import java.util.Vector;

import lotus.domino.Database;
import lotus.domino.NotesException;
import lotus.domino.NotesFactory;
import lotus.domino.Session;
import lotus.domino.View;
import lotus.domino.ViewEntryCollection;




public class GetRead {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {

                Session s = NotesFactory.createSession("192.168.32.156", "Administrator/MyOrg","password");


                Database db =  s.getDatabase("192.168.32.156", "\\mail\\administ.nsf");
                //db.open();
                  View view = db.getView("($Inbox)");
                  ViewEntryCollection vec = view.getAllReadEntries();  
                  System.out.println("View has " +
                          vec.getCount() + " read entries"); 




                } catch (NotesException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

}
```

}

yet, I am getting:

```
NotesException: Not implemented
    at lotus.domino.cso.Base.notImplemented(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.cso.View.getAllReadEntries(Unknown Source)
    at sysgravity.Notes.GetRead.GetRead.main(GetRead.java:21)
```

I have made sure I am using the same notes.jar and NCSO.jar files as on the server, also tried to read [Lotus Notes API giving error while accessing the NSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543346/lotus-notes-api-giving-error-while-accessing-the-nsf) but not luck.

Is it realted to JDK version or eclipse version ?! what do I need to check ?!

EDIT WITH A SOLUTION:
Thanks Richard

for those who are struggling with this issue, here is the detailed solution:
As Richard have highlighted the getallreadentries is implemented in Notes.Jar and NOT NCSO.jar, and specifically it must be a local lotus call.

if you put a server address in the Notesfactory, Notes considers this a remote call and implement notes remote call not a local call through Notes.Jar and this is why you get troubles

the call must be local using:
NotesFactory.createSession((String)null, (String)null, password);

also you must use 
- Java 32 bit for the JDK and JRE when running the jar.
- The computer that is running eclipse or your Jar must be running Lotus Admin + designer or has Notes client installed with the default notes.id properly configured (I found that having multiple notes IDs configured gives issues).
- Configure the PATH in your environment variables to point to Lotus Data File and Notes path.

then it will work.

Thanks, Mahmoud

Comment: You say you are using "the same notes.jar and NCSO..jar files as on the server".  AFAIK, you can only be using one of them, and it appears from the stacktrace that you're using NCSO.jar. But accurate read/unread status information requires access to data that is cached in the Notes client, so it would not surprise me at all that this method was never implemented in NCSO.jar. It could not be accurate.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I have updated my question with the solution, you are sitting in the money but you also need to make local calls as I have stated, Thanks a lot.